# Can I use Cat5e jacks and wiring for POE Cameras?

Tags: cat5e, power-over-ethernet

I have to connect 6 POE cameras to an NVR that provides the POE ports. The cameras will be located 100-200' from the NVR. The packages comes with 100' cables.

I can run new cables, but I have some other options and I'm not an expert with POE so I hope others who know better can help.

There are 2 x 4 sets of Cat-5e jacks located on a wall that would allow me to use 100' cables. Can I plug the 100' cables into these Cat5e jacks and use patch cables from the patch panel in the server room to connect to the NVR? The total length of the longest run would be under 200', and probably closer to 150' so distance isn't an issue. I'm thinking of things like heat or electrical issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This would likely work. Are you sure the NVR provides PoE? Will there be a separate PoE switch? Either way, the distances work out and should be fine.

Easy to test this, right?